# Django fails to login user

Tags: python, django, authentication

Authenticating a user using valid credentials passes on the login view. When `request.user.is_authenticated` is printed, it even outputs True. But after redirecting to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, the request is returned back to `LOGIN_URL` meaning the just authenticated user is no longer authenticated.

The project in concern is a mixed project i.e It uses core django builtin view, route and templating as well as djangorestframework.

djangorestframework TokenAuthentication has worked fine so far, but when i try logging in with core django view i get this weird situation.

I'm using a custom auth user model and two backend authentication ( which are all working fine on api authentication and authorization ). Every other aspect of the project works fine, the only issue is this authentication. I've tried several resource to fix this, but all lead to dead ends. I even used functional based view and django builtin LoginView (as an inherited class and on path route ), same occurence i got irrespective.

## Tools

- Django 3.1.1
- Python 3.8.4
- Postgres
- Postgis
- django restframework 3.11.1

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',

     # installed apps and third party apps
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Account'
PASSWORDLESS_AUTH_BACKEND = 'accounts.auth_backends.PasswordLessAuthenticationBackend'
EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND = 'accounts.auth_backends.EmailAuthenticationBackend'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND, PASSWORDLESS_AUTH_BACKEND
)

LOGIN_URL = '/admin/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/admin/index'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timezone.timedelta(days=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timezone.timedelta(days=2),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'SIGNING_KEY': os.getenv('PROJECT_SECRET_KEY'),
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    
    ...
}
```

**views.py**

```py
class WebAdminLoginView(View):
    """Handles web admin login"""

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """logs in authenticated user account."""
        email, password = request.POST['email'], request.POST['password']
        account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        login(request, account, backend=settings.EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND)
       
        # The below code outputs True
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)            # printsTrue
        return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "admin_login.html")


class IndexListing(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    """Returns a list of all verified partners"""
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'users'
    template_name = 'jadminapp/index/list_users.html'
```

**urls.py**

```py
index_patterns= [
    path(...),
    ....
]

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '',
        core_view.WebAdminLoginView.as_view(),
        name='web-admin-login'
    ),

    path(
        'index', 
        include(
            (index_patterns, 'index'), 
            namespace='index'
        )
    ),
]
```

Comment: This has been fixed. I used ModelBackend provisioned by django in place of my EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION_BACKEND as email is set as my USERNAME_FIELD on my custom model.

Comment: my project structure is same and facing same issue. I have 3 Backend. Please help me, is there any issue with Django 3.1?

Comment: If you've same structure as mine ( i.e email is set as USERNAME_FIELD in your user models ), the approach i took to rectify this issues was, to include [django's model backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) to AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS within settings.py